# How do I solve this integral via integration by parts when it shows a recursion-like behavior?

Tags: integration

I've come across an integral while solving a question for ODE's. The integral is as follows:

$$\int e^{-2x}x\,dx$$

From here I set:

$$
\begin{align}
f(x) = e^{-2x}\quad & f'(x) = -2e^{-2x} \\
g(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^2\quad & g'(x) = x
\end{align}
$$

and continued to solve the integral as follows:

\begin{align}
\int e^{-2x}x\,dx & = e^{-2x}x - \int \left(-2e^{-2x} \times \frac{1}{2}x^2\right)\,dx \\
& = e^{-2x}x + \int \left( e^{-2x}x^2 \right)\,dx
\end{align}

Solving this integral yields:

$$
\int e^{-2x}x\,dx = e^{-2x}x + \frac{2}{3}\int e^{-2x}x^3\,dx
$$

and it continues like this.

How should I proceed to solve this integral? Any tips or advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Switch $f$ and $g$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#LIATE_rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your working is correct, but the way you're using IBP is not helping you to get to the answer.

If I asked you to "solve $2x = 4$", you *could* add $3$ to both sides then times both sides by $50$, but that wouldn't help get to the answer (*find x*). That's what you're doing here. You're not using the formula in the intended way in order to get to the answer.

Have a look at the formula at the top of:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts

With IBP, you're meant to choose $v^\prime(x)$ and $u(x)$ in a way that the integral "reduces" to something "simpler" at each stage, so that eventually you "reduce" the initial integral to an integral you are more familiar with.

So you chose $u(x) =$ the exponential part and $v^\prime(x) = x$

Try it the other way round. Choose $u(x) = x$ and $v^\prime(x) =$ the exponential part.

Because $v^\prime(x)$ goes to $v(x)$, that's basically integrating $v^\prime(x)$ and carrying it over to both terms on the RHS of the equation.

The $u(x)$ gets differentiated on the RHS, and $d/dx(x) = 1$, which gets you a "simpler" integral.

Usually when you have a polynomial and something else in the original integral, you should choose the polynomial $= u(x)$ because then it gets "reduced down" when integrating by parts.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=x$ and $dv=e^{-2x}dx$. Then, $du=dx$ and $v=\dfrac{e^{-2x}}{-2}$

$$\int e^{-2x}xdx=-\frac{xe^{-2x}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\int e^{-2x}dx=-\frac{xe^{-2x}}{2}-\frac{e^{-2x}}{4}+C=-\frac{e^{-2x}}{4}\left(2x+1 \right)+C$$

Answer (score 1):

With $$u=x,v'=e^{-2}$$ we get $$u'=1,v=-\frac{1}{2}e^{-2x}$$ we get
$$\int xe^{2x}dx=-x\frac{1}{2}e^{-2x}-\int\frac{-1}{2}e^{-2x}dx$$